# Search multiple strings from file in multiple files in specific column and output the count in unix shell scripting

Tags: string, shell, lookup

I have searched extensively on the internet about this but haven't found much details.

Problem Description:

I am using aix server.

I have a pattern.txt file that contains customer_id for 100 customers in the following sample format:

160471231

765082023

75635713

797649756

8011688321

803056646

I have a directory (/home/aswin/temp) with several files (1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt and so on) which are pipe(|) delimited. Sample format:

797649756|1001|123270361|797649756|O|2017-09-04 23:59:59|10|123769473
803056646|1001|123345418|1237330|O|1999-02-13 00:00:00|4|1235092
64600123|1001|123885297|1239127|O|2001-08-19 00:00:00|10|1233872
75635713|1001|123644701|75635713|C|2006-11-30 00:00:00|11|12355753
424346821|1001|123471924|12329388|O|1988-05-04 00:00:00|15|123351096
427253285|1001|123179704|12358099|C|2012-05-10 18:00:00|7|12352893

What I need to do search all the strings from pattern.txt file in all files in the directory, in first column of each file and list each filename with number of matches. so if same row has more than 1 match it should be counted as 1.

So the output should be something like (only the matches in first column should count):

1.txt:4

2.txt:3

3.txt:2

4.txt:5

What I have done till now:

cd /home/aswin/temp

grep -srcFf ./pattern.txt * /dev/null >> logfile.txt

This is giving the output in the desired format, but it searching the strings in all columns and not just first column. So the output count is much more than expected.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do that with grep, you must change the pattern.

With your command, you search for pattern in /dev/null and the output is /dev/null:0

I think you want 2>/dev/null but this is not needed because you tell -s to grep.

Your pattern file is in the same directory so grep search in it and output pattern.txt:6

All your files are in the same directory so the -r is not needed.

You put the logfile in the same directory, so the second time you run the command grep search in it and output logfile.txt:0

If you can modify the pattern file, you write each line like ^765082023|
and you rename this file without .txt

So this command give you what you look for.

```
grep -scf pattern *.txt >>logfile
```

If you can't modify the pattern file, you can use awk.

```
awk -F'|' '
NR==FNR{a[$0];next}
FILENAME=="pattern.txt"{next}
$1 in a {b[FILENAME]++}
END{for(i in b){print i,":",b[i]}}
' pattern.txt *.txt >>logfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks ctac for the suggestion. If I don't use /dev/null, the output does not contain filename along with count if the directory has only 1 file. 

1. Modified the pattern file, and ran the following command.

grep -srcFf pattern1.txt * /dev/null >> logfile.txt

The result was 0 match.

2. awk solution worked. But now I am faced with another situation. Say the pattern file contains a string 7650820. If the destination file has 7650820, 76508201, 76508202, 76508203 in the first column, it gives me 4 matches. It should do an exact match and give output as 1. 

Please suggest an edit.

Comment: @Aswin 1)I tell you to modify the pattern file and name it pattern without .txt 2)Your pattern file is now a regex and you have not to use -F in grep.3)You can use -H in place of /dev/null so the command become grep -scHf pattern *.txt >> logfile.4) I can't reproduce your problem with awk, the line $1 in a search if a element of array a has the name $1, so if the name in a is 7650820 and $1=76508201, It's not the same and the instruction b[FILENAME]++ is not executed.

Comment: My mistake. The source file itself had duplicates. Now both suggested solutions are working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks ctac. I applied the awk solution and it worked for a while but now I am faced with another situation. The *.txt file can have multiple rows where the same pattern appears. So if the pattern file has say 5 patterns, the output matches for each file is coming so big numbers like 50 or 70. Can we modify this particular awk solution to count only one occurence of each pattern in the destination files so that the number of matches for each file does not exceed the total number of patterns in the pattern file.